# Проблема с памятью ссд диск, тома

Tags: windows, память, администрирование, диск

Пропала память, раньше на диске Д было 350 гб, а теперь стало 300. Но пустых томов и не использованной памяти нет. Так же интересно что в управлении дисками в снизу он память видит а сверху нет. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена! Оказалась что многие утилиты для распределения памяти между томами видят мою пропавшую память. Я просто убрал свободную память с диска Д (как раз таки потерянные 50 гб) и перекинул ее на диск С. Теперь пк начал видеть всю память.